# how to get alignment or attention information for translations produced by a torch hub model?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, translation, torch, fairseq

The torch hub provides pretrained models, such as: https://pytorch.org/hub/pytorch_fairseq_translation/

These models can be used in python, or interactively with a CLI.
With the CLI it is possible to get alignments, with the `--print-alignment` flag. [The following code](https://fairseq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) works in a terminal, after installing [fairseq](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq) (and pytorch)

```
curl https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fairseq/models/wmt14.v2.en-fr.fconv-py.tar.bz2 | tar xvjf -
MODEL_DIR=wmt14.en-fr.fconv-py
fairseq-interactive \
    --path $MODEL_DIR/model.pt $MODEL_DIR \
    --beam 5 --source-lang en --target-lang fr \
    --tokenizer moses \
    --bpe subword_nmt --bpe-codes $MODEL_DIR/bpecodes \ 
    --print-alignment
```

In python it is possible to specify the keyword args `verbose` and `print_alignment`:

```
import torch

en2fr = torch.hub.load('pytorch/fairseq', 'transformer.wmt14.en-fr', tokenizer='moses', bpe='subword_nmt')

fr = en2fr.translate('Hello world!', beam=5, verbose=True, print_alignment=True)
```

However, this will only output the alignment as a logging message. And for fairseq 0.9 it seems to be broken and results in an error message ([issue](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/issues/1880)).

Is there a way to access alignment information (or possibly even the full attention matrix) from python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've browsed the fairseq codebase and found a hacky way to output alignment information.
Since this requires editing the fairseq sourcecode itself, I don't think it's an acceptable solution. But maybe it helps someone (I'm still very interested in an answer on how to do this properly).

Edit the [sample() function](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/42f65d65776327598a2d3ded2e92e5818c70a125/fairseq/hub_utils.py#L133) and rewrite the return statement.
Here is the whole function (to help you find it better, in the code), but only the last line should be changed:

```
def sample(self, sentences: List[str], beam: int = 1, verbose: bool = False, **kwargs) -> List[str]:
    if isinstance(sentences, str):
        return self.sample([sentences], beam=beam, verbose=verbose, **kwargs)[0]
    tokenized_sentences = [self.encode(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
    batched_hypos = self.generate(tokenized_sentences, beam, verbose, **kwargs)
    return list(zip([self.decode(hypos[0]['tokens']) for hypos in batched_hypos], [hypos[0]['alignment'] for hypos in batched_hypos]))
```